# Where is the following object property allocated?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have the following code and I think that the arr property should be allocated on the heap, because the *test* object is allocated on the heap.
But for some reason, the A destructor is being called, even though I do not call it explicitly. Is there explanation for this?

**CODE:**

```
class A {
public: ~A(){
     cout<< "detor A"<< endl;
 }
};

class C {
    A arr[10];

public: ~C(){
       // delete[]arr;
    }
};
int main() {
    C* test = new C();
    delete test;

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
detor A
detor A
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destructor of an object is called when the object has to be destroyed and independently of the way the object was allocated.

For example:

- a local object is destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope
- an object allocated with `new` is destroyed with `delete`
- a member object is destroyed in the destruction process of its enclosing object

The last cases causes the behavior that you observe: you `delete test`, which requires `arr` to be destroyed, which requires each of its items to be destroyed.